# How are cast votes calculated?

Tags: support, voting, profile-page

I'm just wondering how the votes cast on the profile page are calculated.

[image]

The title implies that it's counting the amount of votes cast, but I don't think that is the case for closures

[image]

I have a feeling I've voted to close questions way more times than the votes cast actually states.

What happens to the close votes that are aged away? 
Are those included in the totals?

Comment: What? The title of the votes cast is "Total number of up and down votes cast" so I don't understand how this got to do with (flags that got) aged away

Comment: @AlonEitan Closure votes I'll edit so it's more clear

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That particular number presents only the total number of up and down votes.
If you hover over the vote count it shows:

> Total number of up and down votes cast

Clicking on it and going into the votes tab in your profile shows you the count of all votes and yes a close vote you casted and aged away still adds to the count since you *did* vote.
You can go to the question and [revote after 14 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99333/please-allow-expired-close-open-votes-to-be-re-cast?lq=1) and this will add to the count.

Comment: so this is an accurate depiction of how many votes i've casted, and It's not missing anything that could be considered a vote?

Comment: yes.. click on "all" tab in votes section to see total count

Answer (score 3):

The 'votes cast' on the profile page are up- and downvotes only; close votes (and reopen votes) do not count. It will match the number of votes in the Votes Cast section on your [profile summary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=summary#user-panel-votes):

[image] 
[image]

It's important to note that it **does not** match with the totals on the [upvotes tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=upvote) and [downvotes tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=downvote); **even though** both 'votes cast' links link to these tabs; these 'votes' tabs only show votes on posts which are not deleted.

[image]